# Entity Framework error with two similar Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two model that link two different db with the same table name.

The two db are managed by the customer and i haven't any authorization for change table name.

I need to copy one row from one db to the other. The code is ok but and i have add one model in the project and one in a dll that i reference in the project.

When i try to use the model i have this error:

> C# MVC Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\nMultiple types with the name 'Example' exist in the EdmItemCollection in different namespaces.  Convention based mapping requires unique names

How can i solve this problem without change table name in the server?

Comment: Could you ask Customer if they can create view with acceptable name for problem table and use view in model instead of table

Comment: Please attention to DataAnnotation on your model. it may not be correctly mapped.

Comment: consider using the [Table(tablename)] attribute to decorate the table class and call the table class what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two databases, but with one or more tables with the same names. Let's say both databases have a table named `TableA`.

You have two DbContext classes, one for each database. It's a bit more complicated if the databases are thus similar (have the same DbSets) that you want to use the same DbContext.

**2 different DbContexts for 2 databases**

The table with name TableA from databaseA represents something different that the table with the same name from databaseB, for instance, TableA from databaseA contains `Persons` and TableA from databaseB contains `Addresses`:

```
class DbContextA : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons {get; set;}
    ...
}
class DbContextB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Via the constructor you could make sure that the DbContexts connect to the correct databases. However, without some model building, entity framework would expect table names Persons and Addresses (maybe a problem with this plural).

Therefore you'll have to tell Entity Framework that Persons should be stored in TableA, and that Addresses should also be stored in TableA.

This is done in [DbContext.OnModelCreating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
protected override OnModelCreating(...)
{
    // Persons should be stored into a table with name TableA
    modelbuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("TableA");
    ...
}
```

Similarly you connect Addresses to TableA.

**1 DbContext for 2 different Databases**

It could be that your two databases are different, but these differences are thus small that you could use the same DbContext class for them, only with some different parameters. Another reason could be that you don't know these parameters at design time.

This makes sense. After all, the purpose of your DbContext is to hide the database behind the DbContext. It could be a SQL database, but it could also be an Excel file, or a CSV file. And even if both databases would be SQL databases, it could be that one database has different table names than the other, or that all decimal values in one database have more precision than the decimal values in the other database.

I meet this problem when my DbContext should be able to work with a slightly different Unit-Test database, or with both Microsoft Sql and MySql.

To solve this, you create a class that contains parameters for modelBuilding. Give an object of this class to your DbContext, and let OnModelCreating use the information in this object to build the database model:

Example: my databases differ in the DateTimeType they use, and the decimal precision

```
class DbModelInfo
{
    public string DateTimeType {get; set;}
    public byte DecimalScale {get; set;}
    public byte DecimalPrecision {get; set;}

    public static DbModelInfo Default
    {
         get
         {
             return new DbModelInfo()
             {
                 DateTimeType = "datetime2";
                 DecimalPrecistion = 19;
                 DecimalScale = 8;
             }
         }
    }

    public static DbModelInfo UnitTesting {...}
}
```

Give the object to your DbContext. OnModelCreating checks if there is an object, if not it could use the Default:

```
class MyDbcontext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbModelInfo DbModelInfo {get; set;}

    public override void OnModelCreating(...)
    {
        // if no model info set, use default
        if (this.DbModelInfo == null)
           this.DbModelInfo = DbModelInfo.Default;

        // set precision of all decimals:
        modelBuilder.Properties<decimal>()
            .Configure(decmal => decmal.HasPrecision(
                this.DbModel.DecimalPrecision, 
                this.DbModel.DecimalScale));
        // set type of all DateTime:
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
            .Configure(datTime => datTime.HasColumnType(this.DbModel.DateTimeType));
    }
}
```